# SPSS issue with RENAME VARIABLES

Tags: unicode, syntax, spss

I have a long syntax (1800 lines) and this one portion has been giving me trouble. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

It is supposed to take an existing file and narrow it down to just the variables listed in the /KEEP statement. Then every variable is renamed to a similar variable name, but "oldxxxx". Later my syntax matches the new file to this updated variable file and points out any changes in the values, giving a list of reasons in the recoded file.

Once the syntax reaches the first RENAME VARIABLES I get the following error:

RENAME VARIABLES Duplicate variable names from RENAME.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The SAVE command does not alter the active dataset, it only drops some variables from the new sav file it creates. If you run something like `ADD FILES FILE = * /KEEP [VARS HERE].`, placing the same variables on the `KEEP` subcommand and then `EXECUTE.` you active dataset should have the same variables as the saved file.

Comment: You can make the syntax clearer by using the DELETE VARIABLES command, which operates on the active file.

Comment: I would suggest you to use  `GET
  FILE='LastAwardingFile.sav(or newfilename. sav) '.
DATASET NAME LastAwardingFile WINDOW=FRONT.` again just before the first `RENAME VARIABLES... `  but this should overwrite if old file name is used.

Answer (score 3):

First a couple of remarks: It would be better practice to save to a different file name. In your syntax the original file gets saved over and you can't go back... Also I recommend you follow @Andy W's advice regarding how to keep only the variables you need in your file.

Now, in the sample syntax you posted I see an error - possibly that's your problem:

`RENAME VARIABLES (total_EMFASYS_award=oldgrant).`

The new name is `oldgrant` instead or `oldtotal_EMFASYS_award`. Possibly further down you've got another command saying

```
RENAME VARIABLES (grant=oldgrant).
```

hence the double name.

**To avoid such errors and shorten your syntax**, you could use the following macro:

```
define renVars (!pos=!cmdend)
rename variables 
!do !i !in (!1) !i = !concat("old",!i)
!doend .
!enddefine.
```

After running this macro definition you can run the macro by stating the macro name and the full list of variables you want renamed, like this:

```
renVars 
Student_ID rl_highschoolgpa comb need qualitygrp NewUpfrontGrant meritgrant 
targetcounty_housing housinggrant  tuitiongrant athlete_recruit .
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note about `RENAME VARIABLES` command - it also works like this:

```
RENAME VARIABLES (list_of_starting_variable_names = list_of_final_variable_names).
```

you would just need to provide the 2 names lists, and the renaming will be done in th eorder in which the names are provided (1st variable in list 1 gets renamed to the 1st variable in list 2,... n-th variable in list 1 into the n-th variable in list 2... and so on.

This should avoid the `Duplicate Variable Names` error you are getting, as all renames are done in one go. But would require you to alter the original syntax a bit, and is a bit harder to spot which variable gets renamed into which variable.